# Nautilus plugin to chmod

Tags: 12.04, permissions, chmod

Some time ago (around Ubuntu 8.04) there was a plugin to Nautilus to change permissions tab in file properties window. It was showing permissions as checkboxes for R/W/X for user/group/others. I can't find it in packages in Ubuntu 12.04. Is there any similar plugin?

This is what I seen in properties tab:
[image]
(screen is actually copied from other askubuntu post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am certain you don't need a plugin now: select a file in your home directory, right click, choose *Properties*, the second tab is *Permissions*.
[image: Permissions tab]

About your comment - thats what *I* see.

**EDIT**
Now I found it - it is no plugin but just a setting, in terminal type

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-advanced-permissions true
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but permissions are viewed as drop-down lists. I'm looking for plugin where there are checkboxes for each permission.

Comment: @Piotr please see the screenshot I added.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Are you using any plugin? See my question above for my screenshot.

Comment: @Piotr, finally I found it :-) see my edited answer please